# What is good W3 total database caching option?

Tags: database, plugin-w3-total-cache

I have a centOS VPS (Apach+Nginx). Right now I use APC for w3 total plugin cache (disk enhanced for page cache). I have less than 25MB database.

I can see several w3tc, APC cache errors. I think the main issue is Zend optimizer. What is the good option for wordperss database cache (eAccelerator, XCache)?

Error.

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of W3_Cache_Apc::delete() should be compatible with W3_Cache_Base::delete($key, $group = '') in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/Cache/Apc.php on line 189
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For database caching you should try Memcached instead, in PHP 5.5, APC for W3 Total Cache will not work like for 5.4 or 5.3.

Comment: Thank you iMadalin. I have a centOS VPS. W3TC shows memcache available for shared server. So if i installed it this VPS it will not cause any issues?

Comment: it should not. If you have memcached php extension and memcached installed and running it will work out of the box in you case. If memcached crushes or isn't started, the cache system will just bypass, your site will be on, but not taking advantage of cache.

Comment: I installed Memcache via EasyApache, but W3TC not detecting it. :( Anyway to fix it? I read somewhere that Memcache use memory memory. Is it true? Update! This is the link:- http://forums.cpanel.net/f189/resolved-memcache-filecache-diskcache-eaccelerator-combinations-347371.html

Comment: I don't have a clue at this moment how is this done with cPanel, I'm maintaing only custom servers with no panel.

Login in your box with ssh, do

`sudo netstat -pant`

you'll find memcached port, configure w3 total cache to that port.

On normal setups, works out of the box without any configuration, on panels like cPanel that change many default things, I don't know.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do i configure w3tc to memcached. When i run "sudo netstat -pant" i get "0 0.0.0.0:587"

Comment: 587 is used by your mta, not memcached server.

common memcached is on 11211 or around it (you can have as many instances you want).

make sure it is started and find the port (on 11211 W3 Total Cache searches by default, so make sure to have it started and also on your vps startup).

Comment: This time memcached installed my host and it working. I guess it has default configuration. Is it ok? Should i adjust memcached memory?

Comment: you need to check that in time with something that shows you memcached statistics. default is good for a power blogger.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at code, going by that error message it's likely more of "strict" check and bad coding practice that error.

Note that you don't *have* to use Object Cache via W3TC, you can just use different implementation for it. [APC Object Cache Backend](http://wordpress.org/plugins/apc/) is long available and battle-tested.

Comment: I don't need to use object cache, I want to use W3TC database cache. This is the error. " PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of W3_Cache_Apc::delete() should be compatible with W3_Cache_Base::delete($key, $group = '') in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/Cache/Apc.php on line 189
"